# Join datasets in R splitting scaling back amounts

Tags: r, merge, left-join, data-wrangling

## Background

I have two datasets with different dimensions for the same unit of observation (let's call them spending lines or programmes, it's a budgeting dataset).

#### **Dataset 1**

Dataset 1 gives us an idea of the function and economic category of spending for each programme in the budget. Let's imagine the budget only has two programmes:

| spending_line | spending_function_COFOG | original_revised | economic_category | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Programme A | 7. Health | Original plans | Staff pay | 7,900 |
| Programme A | 7. Health | Original plans | Purchase of goods and services | 2,000 |
| Programme A | 7. Health | Revised | Staff pay | 8,500 |
| Programme A | 7. Health | Revised | Purchase of goods and services | 2,100 |
| Programme B | 10. Social protection | Original plans | Grants to individuals | 5,000 |
| Programme B | 10. Social protection | Original plans | Staff pay | 2,500 |
| Programme B | 10. Social protection | Revised | Grants to individuals | 3,000 |
| Programme B | 10. Social protection | Revised | Staff pay | 2,500 |

If we were to summarise  by programme and whether it's original budgeted amounts or revised ones, and pivot wider, we'd get the following totals:

| spending_line | Original plans | Revised plans |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Programme A | 9,900 | 10,600 |
| Programme B | 7,500 | 5,500 |
| **Total budget** | **17,400** | **16,100** |

#### **Dataset 2**

Dataset 2 gives us an insight into what's behind the change in spending plans for each programme. Let's continue with the example of a two-programme budget:

| spending_line | original_revised | revision_reason | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Programme A | Revised plans | Baseline spending | 8,100 |
| Programme A | Revised plans | Internal budget-neutral transfers between spending lines | 1,000 |
| Programme A | Revised plans | Accounting adjustments | -500 |
| Programme A | Revised plans | Budget non-neutral increase / decrease | 2,000 |
| Programme B | Revised plans | Baseline spending | 7,000 |
| Programme B | Revised plans | Internal budget-neutral transfers between spending lines | -1,000 |
| Programme B | Revised plans | Accounting adjustments | -300 |
| Programme B | Revised plans | Budget non-neutral increase / decrease | -200 |

As you can see, internal budget-neutral transfers add up to zero (hence why they're budget neutral).

If we summarise Dataset 2 by programme too, it matches the revised budgeted amounts from Dataset 1.

| spending_line | amount |
| --- | --- |
| Programme A | 10,600 |
| Programme B | 5,500 |
| **Total revised budget** | **16,100** |

## Goal

I want to join both datasets in a way that allows me to look at changes in spending plans by function (COFOG) but excluding changes that are due to accounting adjustments or are internal budget-neutral transfers.

## Attempt and problems

I tried to do a *left_join()* from Dataset 1 to Dataset 2, using the variable '*spending_line*' as my key.

The problem is that the amounts get copied for each and every line. Continuing with the mock example of a two-programme budget:

| spending_line | spending_function_COFOG | original_revised | economic_category | revision_reason | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Programme A | 7. Health | Original plans | Staff pay | N/A | 7,900 |
| Programme A | 7. Health | Original plans | Purchase of goods and services | N/A | 2,000 |
| Programme B | 10. Social protection | Original plans | Grants to individuals | N/A | 5,000 |
| Programme B | 10. Social protection | Original plans | Staff pay | N/A | 2,500 |
| Programme A | 7. Health | Revised plans | Staff pay | Baseline spending | 8,100 |
| Programme A | 7. Health | Revised plans | Staff pay | Internal budget-neutral transfers between spending lines | 1,000 |
| Programme A | 7. Health | Revised plans | Staff pay | Accounting adjustments | -500 |
| Programme A | 7. Health | Revised plans | Staff pay | Budget non-neutral increase / decrease | 2,000 |
| Programme A | 7. Health | Revised plans | Purchase of goods and services | Baseline spending | 8,100 |
| Programme A | 7. Health | Revised plans | Purchase of goods and services | Internal budget-neutral transfers between spending lines | 1,000 |
| Programme A | 7. Health | Revised plans | Purchase of goods and services | Accounting adjustments | -500 |
| Programme A | 7. Health | Revised plans | Purchase of goods and services | Budget non-neutral increase / decrease | 2,000 |
| Programme B | 10. Social Protection | Revised plans | Grants to individuals | Baseline spending | 7,000 |
| Programme B | 10. Social Protection | Revised plans | Grants to individuals | Internal budget-neutral transfers between spending lines | -1,000 |
| Programme B | 10. Social Protection | Revised plans | Grants to individuals | Accounting adjustments | -300 |
| Programme B | 10. Social Protection | Revised plans | Grants to individuals | Budget non-neutral increase / decrease | -200 |
| Programme B | 10. Social Protection | Revised plans | Staff pay | Baseline spending | 7,000 |
| Programme B | 10. Social Protection | Revised plans | Staff pay | Internal budget-neutral transfers between spending lines | -1,000 |
| Programme B | 10. Social Protection | Revised plans | Staff pay | Accounting adjustments | -300 |
| Programme B | 10. Social Protection | Revised plans | Staff pay | Budget non-neutral increase / decrease | -200 |

So when I summarise by programme , the revised plans are much larger, in fact they're twice as large:

| spending_line | Original plans | Revised plans |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Programme A | 9,900 | 21,200 (instead of 10,600) |
| Programme B | 7,500 | 11,000 (instead of (5,500) |

I want the revised plan amounts to still reconcile with the totals when I was only looking at Dataset 1. To do so I have to make some assumption - the simplest is that the reasons for the revision apply to spending for all COFOGs and economic categories with the same weights as in the original plans.

Implementing this assumption in this really simple mock example would be very simple. After having joined the datasets, I would mutate the *amount* variable for some rows:

```
df %>%
  mutate(amount = case_when(original_revised == "Revised Plans" ~ (amount / 2),
         TRUE ~ amount) %>%
...
```

I can even generalise it a bit to deal with slightly more complex datasets:

```
df %>%
  mutate(amount = case_when(original_revised == "Revised Plans" ~ (amount /           length(unique(spending_function_COFOG)),
         TRUE ~ amount) %>%
...
```

But even that would not be general enough to account for the reality of my dataset: for each *spending_line*, there's a different number of unique s*pending_function_COFOG* values. If there's no money budget for a certain COFOG, there's simply no row for it, rather than having a constant number of s*pending_function_COFOG* values for each *spending_line* with loads of NAs in *amount.*

How can I solve this? Many thanks in advance!!

Reproducible code:

```r
# We create Dataset 1, with spending function (COFOG) and economic category. 

df1 <- tibble(spending_line = c("Programme A","Programme A", "Programme A", "Programme A", 
                                "Programme B", "Programme B", "Programme B", "Programme B"),
              spending_function_COFOG = c("7. Health", "7. Health", "7. Health", "7. Health", 
                                          "10. Social Protection", "10. Social Protection", "10. Social Protection", "10. Social Protection"),
              original_revised = c("Original", "Original", "Revised", "Revised", 
                                   "Original", "Original", "Revised", "Revised"),
              economic_category = c("Staff pay", "Purchase of goods and services", "Staff pay", "Purchase of goods and services",
                                    "Grants to individuals", "Staff pay", "Grants to individuals", "Staff pay"),
              amount = c(7900, 2000, 8500, 2100,
                         5000, 2500, 3000, 2500))

# We summarise by programme and stage of budget plans. 

df1 %>% 
  group_by(spending_line, original_revised) %>% 
  summarise(amount = sum(amount)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = original_revised, values_from = amount)

# We create Dataset 2, which gives us insight into what has driven the changes in the revised budget plans.

df2 <- tibble(spending_line = c("Programme A","Programme A", "Programme A", "Programme A", 
                                "Programme B", "Programme B", "Programme B", "Programme B"),
              original_revised = c("Revised", "Revised", "Revised", "Revised", 
                                   "Revised", "Revised", "Revised", "Revised"),
              revision_reason = c("Baseline spending", "Internal budget-neutral transfer between spending lines", "Accounting adjustments", "Budget non-neutral increase / decrease",
                                  "Baseline spending", "Internal budget-neutral transfer between spending lines", "Accounting adjustments", "Budget non-neutral increase / decrease"),
              amount = c(8100, 1000, -500, 2000,
                         7000, -1000, -300, -200))

# Again, we summarise by programme and stage of budget plans, and we see that it reconciles with the Revised budgets from df1.

df2 %>% 
  group_by(spending_line, original_revised) %>% 
  summarise(amount = sum(amount)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = original_revised, values_from = amount)

# Now we join the two datasets based on programme and whether they are original or revised. 

joint_df <- left_join(x = df1, y = df2, by = c("spending_line", "original_revised"))

# We pass the amount from Dataset 1 to the amounts of Dataset 1 where it was original plans (hence with no info on Dataset 2)
# drop amount.x, rename amount.y as it's the only numerical value left in the dataset, and again we group by programme and whether
# it's original or revised budget plans. We can see how the original ones still match, but the revised ones are twice as large
# as they should be. 

joint_df %>% 
  mutate(amount.y = case_when(original_revised == "Original" ~ amount.x,
                              TRUE ~ amount.y)) %>% 
  select(!amount.x) %>% 
  rename(amount = amount.y) %>%
  group_by(spending_line, original_revised) %>% 
  summarise(amount = sum(amount)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = original_revised, values_from = amount)
```

Comment: Please share data in a [reproducible format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so we can copy/paste the values and code for testing. If the rows always line up, you can just use `cbind()` or `bind_cols()` to merge the dataset. If you don't have unique IDs, doing a join won't be helpful.

Comment: Hi @MrFlick, I have added the data in reproducible format now, sorry for that.

Comment: @XavierVillàAguilar you forgot to include your desired output for the example!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want something like this?

```
left_join(df2, 
          distinct(df1, spending_line, spending_function_COFOG),
          by = join_by(spending_line)) |>
  filter(!revision_reason %in% c("Internal budget-neutral transfer between spending lines", "Accounting adjustments")) |>
  summarise(amount = sum(amount), .by = c(spending_function_COFOG, revision_reason))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  spending_function_COFOG revision_reason                        amount
  <chr>                   <chr>                                   <dbl>
1 7. Health               Baseline spending                        8100
2 7. Health               Budget non-neutral increase / decrease   2000
3 10. Social Protection   Baseline spending                        7000
4 10. Social Protection   Budget non-neutral increase / decrease   -200
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for this. It works for this mock example, but in my real life dataset, using distinct() for spending_line and spending_function_COFOG still leads to some spending_lines being there more than once, because they have more than one COFOG associated to them. 

Therefore, when I do the merge, amounts are larger for those spending_lines - not for the ones that had only one distinct combination.

Comment: @XavierVillàAguilar which COFOG would you like to choose, in the situation where there are multiple?